# Issues loading Google JS library in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, static-resources, google-map

I am trying to load the google places library into an LWC.
I ripped the js from the src url(below) for a normal google script tag and loaded it as a static resource.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={MY_KEY}&libraries=places
```

My LWC is simple:

```
<template>
    <lightning-input 
        type="search"
        label="Street" 
        onchange={handleKeyChange}
    </lightning-input>
</template>
```

My Js controller:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import googleApi                 from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/Google_Apis"
import { loadScript }            from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
export default class QuoteAddressQuestion extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback(){
        loadScript(this, googleApi + '/google-places-api.js').then(() => {
            console.log("Script Loaded");
        });
    }
    handleKeyChange(event) {
        google.maps.places.AutocompleteService.getQueryPredictions({ input: "1600 Pennsylvania Ave" }, 
        (predictions) => {
            predictions.forEach((prediction) => {
                console.log(prediction.description);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

So I ask, is this possible?

I am getting loading errors "Loading the Google Maps JavaScript API without a callback is not supported:" and when I hit the keyChanged function I get "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." on a few of the google common and util js files. I have added an entry for the CSP trusted sites and the CORS origins list. But no luck.

Has anyone ever tried this before?

Comment: When you load the script in LWC it's always available in the window object. 
Have you tried logging the google variable in handleKeyChange to check if google is undefined or not?
Also, try the window.google.maps.places.AutocompleteService.getQueryPredictions

Comment: @MukulMahawariya I have logged out the google object and am able to see the object and prototype functions inside, but the getQueryPredictions callback function is never called.